# Neural network with string data

Tags: r, machine-learning

I am new to Neural Networks. I am trying to build a neural network with `R` with the following data:

> concrete_model <- neuralnet(formula = Result ~ FrName1 + FrName2, data
>   = model_data)

`FrName1` and `FrName2` are containing values for contact first names.

When I execute I am getting below error:

> Error in neurons[[i]] %*% weights[[i]] :    requires numeric/complex
>   matrix/vector arguments

I believe that neural network only works with numerical data. But how to use NN for data that contains `String` values?

Answer (score 0):

If your data has string values, you need to convert the to numeric.

First approach is to replace each unique value with a number. Second - creating dummy variables for each unique value.

If you have too many unique values, you'd need to deal with it first: combine some categories.

Also you may replace unique values with mean value of target for this unique value of the feature.

Comment: Thank you Andrey. I tried to convert my data to numeric using as.numeric(). But it resulted in creating lots of NA's indicating failure in conversion. I tried model.matrix as well but resulted in lot of unique values. Any suggestion will be of great help.

Comment: The way of transforming data heavily depends on the data itself. In the main post you wrote that the variables contain first names? What do you plan to predict with such a data?

Comment: Hi Andrey.  The logic goes like this - If the FrName1  and FrName2 are same I am predicting that the mail sent is from authorized person. If both are different its a unauthorized mail. I was able to transform data to numeric values using as.numeric(). I am transforming data from factors to numeric. Thank you.

Comment: Hm, interesting. Then I have one more question: why do you need machine learning here? One simple rule of comparison (equal or not) will give 100% accuracy. Well, if you really want to use machine learning here, you can try to transform the data: create new columns -  Name1 and Name2. All values in Name1 will be 1. If FrName1 = FrName2, then value in Name 2 will be 1, otherwise 0. This way you'll be able to train the network on these two new columns.

Answer (score 0):

you may use the decimal convertion of each character in the word concatenated without spaces (as a word), each word may be placed in an array or vector, put it all together in a variable, then train the Neural Network (?)